# How to change font of text having multiple font

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm developing an app like MS WordPad, however I've noticed that when try to change multiple selected `Fonts` or font sizes there is no way to obtain what the original font or size was as the `RichTextBox.SelectedFont` would return null with multiple fonts. So at the moment I have to iterate through each character of the selected text and change them one by one...This is extremely slow even on a fast PC.

So I was wondering if there is any better way of doing it?

Comment: You'll probably have to keep track of each change to get what the original font/size was.

Comment: can you pls explain me how can i do this.

Comment: If the user is allowed to change the font, add code where you're changing the font and save the information.  Most likely you'll need a custom collection that will accept each character and a sub collection of fonts so that you can back up to any one in the sub collection

Comment: I think this idea work great if we have a limited text in our selection. but its worthless with large selection of text like 10000 Characters.

Comment: 10000 characters in a collection with a font collection of 2 or 3 for each one should be peanuts for most computers.  If you inherit from `IEnumerable` for the collection you'll find it quite fast.